# How many real roots the equation possess

Tags: graphing-functions

$$e^x=m(m+1),\; m<0$$                   I draw the graph of R.H.S and LHS and got it intersect at one point . But i dont know whether my procedure is right or wrong. Plz help me.                      The options are 1) no real root.    2) exactly one.  3) two real roots.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Please format your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). You can also show some effort by showing your work and clarifying where you are stuck on.

Comment: The most straightforward way would be to look at the graph of $e^x - m(m+1)$. Since $e^x$ is strictly increasing, what does this tell you about the roots?

Comment: Thank you Toby Mak. Since x and m are different variables how would be the graph drawn for e^x -m(m+1).  This is the matter of trouble for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plot the curves for some values of $m<0$, e.g. $m=-2$ or $m=-1/2$. What do you find?

Since $e^x$ is strictly increasing, there is at most one real solution.
**If** there is a real solution then it is $x=\ln(m(m+1))$. Now you have to look for values of $m$ with $m(m+1) > 0$. I guess you can continue.